# Angular filter range with grater than values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, filter, range

I want to create filter range based on Angular. This is my html input:

```
<input type="range" min="100" max="2000"step="100"
data-ng-model="value" >
```

When I use it, it filters some values and shows in ng-repeat:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="x in names | rangeFilter:'Cost':value  ">
{{ x.Cost}}
</div>
```

These are values from json:

```
{"records":[{"Name":"First","Cost":"500"},{"Name":"Second","Cost":"300"},{"Name":"Third","Cost":"700"}]}
```

And my filter:

```
angular.module('app.filter.range',[])
    .filter('rangeFilter', function () {
    return function (items, attr, min) {
        var range = [];
        for (var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; i++){
            var item = items[i];
            if(item[attr]>=min){
                range.push(item);
            }


        }
        return range;
    };
});
```

It should shows records which have Cost values grather or equal than value in range input bar.
And it actually works to the "1000" value. When the input value is f.ex 400, it shows Costs of the First and Third Record. When is grater than 700, does not show any record, which is fine (cause the third record, the greatest, is 700). But when the input rage is greater than 1000 it shows all records, despite the fact that it is grater than Cost values in records. What is the problem? Thanks for the solution in advance :)

**Edit:**
One more thing. Json is imported from the server:

```
.controller('Ctrl',[
    '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){
    $http.get(path)
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response.data;
        }
        );
```

When i put values directly into controller it works:

```
$scope.names = [
    { Nazwa: 'First', Kwota: 500  },
    { Nazwa: 'Second', Kwota: 300  },
    { Nazwa: 'Third', Kwota: 700  }         
];
```

Do You have any ideas? :)

Comment: did you try debugging and check what value you get inside the filter when you select a range of 1000?

Comment: Hmm.. i got error in console:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

(l=items.lengtth) - but why?